# Converting an equation into a function of time.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Consider this equation.

$$l\ddot \theta + \ddot x_o \cos \theta + (g-\ddot y_o)\sin \theta =0$$

$\ddot X$ means $\frac{d^2X}{dt^2}$.

It is the equation of a pendulum with moving pivot.Where:

$F_x$, $F_y$, $F_g$, $l$ and $\theta$ are shown on the picture.
$(x_o,y_o)$ is the coordinate of the pivot.
$(x,y)$ is the coordinate of the bob.

You don't have to do much about the physics aspect of the problem.

What I need is a function of time that tells the amount of angle $\theta$ receiving $\ddot x_o(t)$ and $\ddot y_o(t)$.

like this (I mean in this format):

$$\theta(t)=f(\ddot x_o(t),\ddot y_o(t))$$

for better comprehension, I mention add this picture.

[image: pendulum]

Also in my case : $\ddot y_o=0$ <--------******************
you can leave it out.

Comment: It is very hard to solve this kind of differential equation, even in the simpler case of simple pendulum. You may find a numerical solution using integrator like Runge-Kutta and similar.

Comment: Are you happy with a result for small amplitude oscillations? In that case, you can actually give $\theta(t)$ in terms of the input functions $(x_0,y_0)$. On the other hand, if the pivot is not externally driven but freely moving, the dynamical equation for $(x_0,y_0)$ has to be taken into account as well. Maybe we do need to know a bit more about the physics of the problem after all; it seems like a textbook problem to me.

Comment: the pivot is moving with constant acceleration. I mean $\ddot x_o$. this may simplify the problem. of course this is not a problem. this is a real phenomenon I am dealing with!

Comment: Naturally, how I could possibly think otherwise is beyond me. So, $\ddot{x}_0$ is constant, and $\ddot{y}_0 = 0$, right? Any thoughts about my previous question on small amplitude oscillations?

Comment: @FritsVeerman .right. amplitude is not small it may even come to 1.5 rad. and also remember the motion is not harmonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap up the above discussion, the ODE to solve is
\begin{equation}
l\,\frac{\text{d}^2 \theta}{\text{d} t^2} + a_0\,\cos \theta + g\,\sin \theta = 0,
\end{equation}
with $l,a_0,g$ free parameters. As there is no friction, the system is nicely conservative and can therefore be integrated; the associated conserved quantity gives the first order ODE
\begin{equation}
\frac{l}{2} \left(\frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t}\right)^2 +a_0\, \sin \theta - g \cos \theta = \text{constant}.
\end{equation}
By shifting the angle $\theta$ as
\begin{equation}
 \theta \to \phi = \theta - \text{arctan}\, \frac{g}{a_0}
\end{equation}
and introducing the rescaled time
\begin{equation}
 t \to \tau = \left(\frac{g^2 + a_0^2}{l^2}\right)^\frac{1}{4} t,
\end{equation}
the first order ODE above simplifies to
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\text{d} \phi}{\text{d} \tau}\right)^2 + \sin \phi = \text{constant},
\end{equation}
which is the [standard pendulum equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_%28mathematics%29); this can be [solved](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve[1%2F2%20f%27[t]%5E2%20%2B%20Sin[f[t]]%3D%3DA%2Cf[t]%2Ct]) explicitly using [elliptic functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16).

Comment: What is ODE?  and which is the function I talked about?

Comment: An ODE is an ordinary differential equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation). The function you mentioned can be found if you solve the differential equation for $\phi$ as explained in the answer.